# Can a asp.net MVC controller class return Action Method and Json both?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Thanks for your time , I have a simple question, in an asp.net MVC application, inside controllers is it possible that along with some methods returning View (ActionMethods) other could act as (or return) Json as a Web API (could be called from external apps).

Just trying to do a proper separations, hence trying to understand.

Thanks much.

Comment: An MVC controller action can certainly return JSON, hence there being a `Json` method that is a member of the `Controller` class and returns a `JsonResult`. Such a method is normally called from the script in a view as an AJAX call though. If you want a Web API then create a Web API separately.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: JsonResult would pass it to the internal views, I am trying to expose it to http(s) aswell, so I think not a good match right ?

Comment: you can make it condition wise return result like if its ajax request then return json else return your view. you can check request is ajax using Request.IsAjaxRequest()

Answer (score 0):

You can make an action function like an API. Try something like the this.

```
// Controller/Action
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult IAmSpecial()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        string[] objects = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" };

        return Json(objects);
    }

    return View();
}
```

This will return the `IAmSpecial` view if you browse to `{domain}/{Controller}/IAmSpecial` while it will return a JSON result if you use an AJAX Http Get request on the same url.

Comment: what about the single responsibility principle?

Comment: I'm just answering the `is it possible` question but this type of practice is undesirable and should be avoided. There's a reason why there is ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API which is as you said for separation of concerns and the single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 0):

while it is possible to have controller methods which return Json data only, there are a number of considerations when you want to expose that data outside of the UI app.

Since you have an MVC app, I expect you have users and a way to login.  Your controllers would more than likely be secured in some way, which works for the internal users of the application. Now you want to add one method which effectively becomes an API, available outside of the application and calls to it will have to be authenticated somehow.

What I would suggest is to split this up. You can create a separate project, which is a WebAPI one, in the same solution. The code which prepares the data can live in a class library you can then reference in both your MVC and WebAPI projects.

Your MVC app can call it and then return a view with that data, the WebAPI calls it and simply returns the data. You can now decide on a way of securing your API, maybe using Identity Server or some other way and you can keep adding things to it, without affecting the UI layer.

Your second option is to make the MVC app use the API when it needs to retrieve data, so both your public clients and UI use the same thing.

Whichever option you use, the idea is to not duplicate anything and at the same time provide the security layers you need.